# I plan to go US, Can I take my portable charge to the airplane? It is a EasyAcc 20000mAh power bank

Tags: air-travel, batteries

[image]

I plan to go US, Can I take my portable charger( lilon battery, portable power bank) to the airplane? the capacity is [20000mah](http://www.easyacc.com/644-easyacc-monster-20000mah-power-bank.html).Different countries make rules about whether Power Banks are allowed to be used on flights or not so please tell me.